# How to prevent majestic 12 from indexing a site

Tags: apache-2.2, search-engine

We experience a lot of traffic and server load on a web server.

All I can find out is majestic12 accessing pages all the time.

I wonder how I can prevent majestic12 from indexing the site

Do they respect any robots.txt entry and how do I write such an enty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Majestic 12's own page about robots.txt](http://www.majestic12.co.uk/projects/dsearch/mj12bot.php), they fully respect robots exclusion (3rd answer from the top). The robots.txt file is a plain text file in the root of your website, i.e. you place it at:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/robots.txt
```

and have these lines in the file:

```
User-agent: MJ12bot
Disallow: /
```

So if you want to block that bot, I see no problem -- unless you're getting hammered by one of the fake bots they mention.

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I didn't find the faq on their pages but now i have it. I wonder if they have mentioned all fake bots. Why would someone claim to be majestic12?

Answer (score 3):

For the op's follow up question:

> I wonder if they have mentioned all
>   fake bots. Why would someone claim to
>   be majestic12?

That would be a false flag operation. Virus disguises itself as a legit bot/process to crawl ip's. The explanation is on [the majestic12 faq](http://www.majestic12.co.uk/projects/dsearch/mj12bot.php#WhatIsIt) way down.